# $k$ points of contact for percolation

Tags: probability-theory, percolation

In Grimmett's book on percolation near the beginning of Ch. 7, he summarizes the plan of proof of the result on percolation of slabs.  We are in $\mathbb{Z}^d, d\ge2$, with his usual notation that $B_m$ means a box of sidelength $2m$.  $d$ and $p$ for which the percolation probability $\theta_p$ is positive are fixed.  One claim he makes is that if $\epsilon>0$, $k\ge1$, $m\ge1$ are given for which $P_p(B_m\leftrightarrow \infty)>1-\epsilon$ then there is some $n>2m$ for which $P_p(B_m\leftrightarrow \text{ at least k distinct points in }\partial B_n)>1-2\epsilon$.  I am having trouble establishing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He establishes a result that implies this in Lemma (7.9):

> If $\theta(p) > 0$ and $\eta > 0$, there exists integers $m = m(p, \eta)$ and $n = n(p, \eta)$ such that $2m < n$ and
>   $$P_p(B(m) \leftrightarrow  K(m,n) \, \textrm{in}\, B(n)) > 1 - \eta$$

Is there an issue you are having with the proof of that lemma?